# Project development with React Native

Tags: mobile, react-native, mobile-development

I development project with react-native-cli and my customer want to see job progress. 
I can send him an apk-file after every change, but it's not very convenient. Are there any services that help automate this process? 
Can I deploy a project in any store(play market, etc..)?

Please, share your experience if you have worked with mobile development. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution will be React Native CodePush, which is a cloud service that enables React Native developers to deploy mobile app updates instantly.

CodePush allows you to change your application’s code such as updating either the JavaScript code (e.g. making bug fixes, adding new features) or image assets, release it, and have your customers get the new version almost immediately. It doesn’t require the end-user to upgrade to a new version from the app store or play store.

For more information check their [official documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push).

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can deploy the project to google play store or any other service like that but the problem is that it would require even more work then building the APK. If your client has technical knowledge then what i would suggest is having a git or bitbucket repository and then share the repo with your client. That way you he/she can track all your commits.